# Could someone help me with an problem with complex number's arguments?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I know that the argument of a complex number has something to do with its trigonometric form... But I don't understand a lot further... And I have this problem; Let $z$, $z'$ and $z''$ be complex number, all with an argument of $\frac{2\pi}{5}$. What is the argument of $z\cdot(z'+z'')$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euler representation of a complex number? i.e. $z = \lvert z \rvert \exp(i \cdot arg(z))$?
Hint: What meaning does the argument have when we talk about the representation of a complex number as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$? What happens when you add two vectors pointing in the same direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its $\dfrac{4\pi}{5}$.

Because let us represent a complex number as $(r,\theta)$. Then if $z=(r,\theta)$ and $z'=(R,\theta)$, we have that $z+z'=(r+R,\theta)$, and that $zz'=(rR,2\theta)$.

We can see this from $z=re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

You're given

$$\begin{cases}z=r_1e^{2\pi i/5}\\z'=r_2e^{2\pi i/5}\\z''=r_3e^{2\pi i/5}\end{cases}\;\;\implies z(z'+z'')=r_1e^{2\pi i/5}\left(r_2e^{2\pi i/5}+r_3e^{2\pi i/5}\right)=$$$${}$$

$$=e^{2\pi i/5}e^{2\pi i/5}\left[r_1(r_2+r_3)\right] ...$$

Answer (score 0):

So, when $\text{a}\space\wedge\space\text{b}\space\wedge\space\text{c}\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\arg(\text{a})=\arg(\text{b})=\arg(\text{c})=\frac{2\pi}{5}$ we get:

$$\text{a}\cdot\left(\text{b}+\text{c}\right)=\left|\text{a}\right|e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\cdot\left(\left|\text{b}\right|e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}+\left|\text{c}\right|e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\right)=\left|\text{a}\right|\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\cdot\left(\left|\text{b}\right|+\left|\text{c}\right|\right)=$$
$$\left|\text{a}\right|\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}+\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\cdot\left(\left|\text{b}\right|+\left|\text{c}\right|\right)=\left|\text{a}\right|\cdot e^{\frac{4\pi i}{5}}\cdot\left(\left|\text{b}\right|+\left|\text{c}\right|\right)=\left|\text{a}\right|\cdot\left(\left|\text{b}\right|+\left|\text{c}\right|\right)\cdot e^{\frac{4\pi i}{5}}$$